# C Programming - Passing a pointer to array

Tags: c, pointers

How do I pass a pointer value to an array of the struct;

For example, on a txt I have this:

```
John Doe;xxxx@hotmail.com;214425532;
```

My code:

```
typedef struct Person{
    char name[100];
    char email[100];
    int phone;
}PERSON;

int main(){
   PERSON persons[100];
    FILE *fp;
    char *ap_name;
    char *ap_email;
    char *ap_phone;
    char line[100];
    fp=("text.txt","r");
    if(fp==NULL){
        exit(1);
    }
    else{
        fgets(line,100,fp);
        ap_name=strtok(line,";");
        ap_email=strtok(NULL,";");
        ap_phone=strtok(NULL,";");
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

My question is how can I pass the value of ap_name, ap_email, ap_phone to the struct?
And, do I need to use all of these pointers?

Comment: Try `man strcpy`.  And probably `strtol` if you need the phone number as an integer (which I personally think is a bad idea, but to each his own).

Comment: You can't pass anything to a struct.  It's a data structure, not a procedure.  You can assign to members of the struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name and email are relatively easy; just use `strcpy` (or `strncpy`);

```
strncpy(persons[i].name, ap_name, sizeof persons[i].name - 1);
```

This will copy the contents of the string pointed to by `ap_name` into the name field of the struct.  At most `sizeof persons[i].name - 1` (100 - 1, or 99) characters will be copied into `persons[i].name`, and if the length of the string pointed to by `ap_name` is less than that, then 99 - strlen(ap_name) nul characters (ASCII 0) are appended.  Same thing for email:

```
strncpy(persons[i].email, ap_email, sizeof persons[i].email - 1);
```

Note that this assumes that the length of ap_name and ap_email will always be less than the destination buffers; as written, your code pretty much guarantees this, but extra sanity checking may not be a bad idea.

As for the phone number, a regular int may not be (and most likely won't be) wide enough to hold a 10-digit number, assuming you're storing area code or extensions (the minimum range guaranteed by the language standard is `[-32767,32767]`).  Not to mention that phone numbers are generally represented with non-numeric characters, such a `(999)-999-9999`.  You may want to store this information as a string as well.

EDIT

Another alternative for the phone number is to use a wider numeric type (preferably unsigned):

```
struct PERSON {
   ...
   unsigned long phone;
   ...
};
```

and then convert the string using `strtoul()`:

```
persons[i].phone = strtoul(ap_phone, NULL, 10);
```

The `strtoul()` library function will convert a string representation of a number into the equivalent numerical value.

Answer (score 2):

Use `strncpy` to copy a string to its corresponding struct element.

You might want to make your `phone` element a string rather than an int (phone numbers typically contain non-numeric characters). If it really has to be an int then use `atoi` or `strtol` to convert the `ap_phone` string to an int, and then just assign this value to phone.

Comment: Assigning a string to an integer?

Comment: You can only assign to phone after converting the string to a number.

Comment: +1 for "You might want to make your phone element a string rather than an int (phone numbers typically contain non-numeric characters)."

Comment: I think you meant **strncpy()** ?

Comment: @Tim: yes, I guess I did mean `strncpy`. ;-)

Comment: strncpy is a extension of strcoy, the difference is that we can choose the numbers of characters....
 I want that when i want to printf("Name %s\n",persons[i].name);

Comment: @Pedro: the reason for using strncpy in this particular case is to ensure that you do not over-run the fixed size char arrays in your struct.

Comment: @Pedro: update your question to show your latest code with strncpy calls and then we can help you to get it working

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is what you're asking, but:

When you have a structure, each member is just accessed with the . operator.

```
persons[0].name
persons[3].email
persons[10].phone
```

Are all valid operators to get the 0th person's name, the 3rd person's email or the 10th person's phone number. Each of those is a separate variable that can be treated as anything else.

Comment: i know that...what i want is to pass the value of pointer to the struct